# Access jsonb value[] by key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am currently storing data in a jsonb column on a postgres db in the following format:
`{"ids": [4, 3, 2, 1]}` where the value is an array of integers.

I wish to do the following:

1. Locate rows where the column contains the value of 4 in the value
   array for the 'ids' key.
2. Locate rows where the column contains the values 2,3, & 1 in the       value array for the 'ids' key.

My most recent attempt use the following

`select * from tablename WHERE (column_name -> ids)::integer[] && ARRAY[1,3]`

Which gave me a type casting error at ::integer[] `ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to integer[]`

I suspect I was trying to cast the 'ids' portion and needed to go a level deeper, but I'm unsure how (if that is even the right approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the contains operator `@>`

```
select * 
from tablename 
WHERE column_name @> '{"ids":[4]}'
```

This also works for multiple values:

```
select * 
from tablename 
WHERE column_name @> '{"ids":[1,2,3]}'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7907e779df69ed95eb1c8427823f56f8)

Comment: @ИгорьТыра: yes it will return those, see the online example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE column_name -> 'ids' @> '[4]'::jsonb
SELECT * from tablename WHERE column_name -> 'ids' @> '[2,3,1]'::jsonb
```

Comment: I get a syntax error at '->' in Postico and no returns in psql with these queries. @a_horse_with_no_name 's solution worked for me. Why would I get a syntax error at -> as I know it's a valid operator?

Comment: dont know about Postico, but psql operator @> may be version dependant, I tried my code with @a_horse_with_no_name's fiddle and it works with v12 and v11

Comment: That could be it. I was using 9.6.